# np.nansum ignores zeros in Counters

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have two counters in python: counter1 and counter2. When I try to perform np.nansum on them, one of the fields is ignored because it contains zeros (if i change values to non-zeros the code works fine). Is there any workaround to get all the input keys in the output dict?

```
counter1 = Counter({'sensitivity': 1.0, 'dice': 1.0, 'specificity': 1.0, 'precision': 1.0, 'c-factor': 0.0})
counter2 = Counter({'sensitivity': 1.0, 'dice': 1.0, 'specificity': 1.0, 'precision': 1.0, 'c-factor': 0.0})
c = np.nansum([counter1, counter2])
```

the result i get is:

```
c= Counter({'sensitivity': 2.0, 'specificity': 2.0, 'dice': 2.0, 'precision': 2.0})
```

to compare, when i do:

```
counter1 = Counter({'sensitivity': 1.0, 'dice': 1.0, 'specificity': 1.0, 'precision': 1.0, 'c-factor': 0.1})
counter2 = Counter({'sensitivity': 1.0, 'dice': 1.0, 'specificity': 1.0, 'precision': 1.0, 'c-factor': 0.1})
c = np.nansum([counter1, counter2])
```

i get:

```
c=Counter({'sensitivity': 2.0, 'specificity': 2.0, 'dice': 2.0, 'precision': 2.0, 'c-factor': 0.2})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887125/adding-counters-deletes-keys). If you need to `update` if you want to keep zeros. Try doing:

```
c=np.nansum(counter1).copy()   #I don't know why you use np.nansum, but you can pass it like this
c.update(np.nansum(counter2))
c
>>Counter({'c-factor': 0.0,
     'dice': 2.0,
     'precision': 2.0,
     'sensitivity': 2.0,
     'specificity': 2.0})
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, that was the solution I needed. I use the nansum because sometimes c-factor value is a nan (which is correct) and I just want to ignore those values when calculating the sum.